# change the background positioning area

Tags: css, background, background-image

I am using the CSS3 contain value. It seems to be what I want in that it will adjust the background image as the window is resized. However, the background viewing/positioning area allows the image to resize only so far. 
Cover works except that when the window is resized to very large position, not all of the image is visible. see here: [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

```
body {
     background:url('images/bg.jpg') no-repeat fixed;
     background-size: contain;
}
```

I would like the background image to at least take up all of the area containing content (header, content, footer area).
This seems to be what needs to be solved: "The image is rendered, preserving its intrinsic proportion, at the largest size contained within, or covering, the background positioning area". [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)
How does the background positioning area get changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all of the image is visible because, obviously, the dimensions of the image are nearly square, but when you resize the browser to a full screen, typically the screen is quite a bit wider than it is tall.

I presume it's the dandelions that you don't wish to be cut off in that particular image. A simple fix would be to position it so that it is fixed to the bottom of the screen and allow the top to be cut off.

```
body {
   background:url('images/bg.jpg') no-repeat center bottom fixed;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

There is more discussion of full page background image techniques, including a code to make it work in MSIE as well, [on css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: Perfect solution! Positioning area was sending off red flags, but I think I was over-complicating the problem. Reminds me to keep things simple.

Answer (score 0):

There is a route you can take where you use the img element to put the image behind the text, in my jsfiddle the first segment of the code is with the image behind the text not using the background code.

The second one is using CSS. It will take some extra css coding but this is just a possibility of what you can do. Again, this may not be your answer, but a thought of what you can do.

http://jsfiddle.net/mmsD5/

```
#l1 {
overflow: hidden;
```

}

```
#l1 p{
width: auto;
max-height: auto;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
color: #fff;
```

}

```
#l1 img {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
z-index: 1;
```

}

```
#l2 {
position: absolute;
top: 40em;
background: url(http://stylegerms.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Techno-Desktop-backgrounds-Desktop-Wallpaper.jpg) no-repeat;
```

}

Comment: That actually may come in handy elsewhere, Thanks Cam.

Comment: Ghoppe has the correct answer, but it wont work in anything below ie9, (bleh to IE). Hope that helps.